# Javascript function to check if a dropdown has same values

Tags: javascript

In a simple form how can I check that a particular dropdown which is dynamically generated 'n' times does not have the same value on click of 'submit' button.

Comment: And what have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

Execute `.each()` on a common jQuery selector and store each value for comparison in an array.

Now compare the length of the array storing your original values to the array returned by the [underscore.js `_.unique` function](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq).

I'll give you better example code when you: (state what you have tried) and ((accept some more answers) or (give a good reason why you only have a 17% accept rate))